# How to disable a field in crispy form django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am using crispy form to let user create a new issue post, but I want user not change 'project' field', so that issues can be put under the right project. I used `form.fields['project'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` ,but this one only has styling disable effect, not really functionally.

[image]

models.py

```
def new_issue(request, project_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IssueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            issue = form.save(commit=False)
            issue.author = request.user
            issue.save()
            return redirect('project:issue_tracker:issue_detail',project_id=project_id,issue_id=issue.id)
    else:
        form = IssueForm(initial={'project': project_id})
        form.fields['project'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    template = 'issue_tracker/issue/new_issue.html'
    context = {'form': form,'project_id':project_id}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)

class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')

class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')
```

new_issue.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add New Issue </h1>
    <form method="POST" class="Issue-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you use Django-1.9 or higher?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the value to *readonly* is *not* enough. This only has impact on how the HTML has been rendered. Depending on what the browser does in that case, it is possible that the user can still edit the form field.

But nevertheless, even if the user can not edit the form, a person with some knowledge of how HTTP requests work, can still maliciously enter value in the request, and therefore thus change values in the database that are not supposed to get changed.

## [django-1.9](/questions/tagged/django-1.9) and higher

Since [djang-1.9](/questions/tagged/djang-1.9), you can alter the [**`.disabled`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) attribute on a form. In that case not only will this render the field as disabled or readonly, it will also prevent a person from maliciously entering values. If the user enters some data, that data is simply ignored (for that specific field). So we can write:

```
def new_issue(request, project_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IssueForm(request.POST, initial={'project': project_id})
        form.fields['project'].disabled = True
        if form.is_valid():
            issue = form.save(commit=False)
            issue.author = request.user
            issue.save()
            return redirect('project:issue_tracker:issue_detail',project_id=project_id,issue_id=issue.id)
    else:
        form = IssueForm(initial={'project': project_id})        
        form.fields['project'].disabled = True
    template = 'issue_tracker/issue/new_issue.html'
    context = {'form': form,'project_id':project_id}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Note that you will probably need some `initial` or an `instance`, since otherwise, there is no data at all to fallback on.

### Moving this into the form

In the above code fragment, we wrote the same expression twice: each time we construct a form. This is against the DRY principle. Typically you specify the field, or - for example in the case the field is not always disabled, you can specify that by overriding the `__init__` constructor.

For example:

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __int__(self, *args, disabled_project=True, **kwargs):
        super(IssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].disabled = disabled_project

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')
```

So now we can use a parameter to initialize the `IssueForm`, and specify if the `disabled_project` flag is `True` or `False`.

## [django-1.8](/questions/tagged/django-1.8) and lower

In case you work with *older* Django versions (not recommended, since there is no support anymore), we can still however ensure that the data is ignored, by adding a `clean_somefield` function. For example:

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        widget = self.fields['project'].widget
        widget.attrs['readonly'] = widget.attrs['disabled'] = widget.disabled = True

    def clean_project(self):
        return self.instance.project

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')
```

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: This is really awesome!! Works very well!!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.  Struggled with "readonly" for a while but your answer is golden.

Answer (score 0):

May be making that field `readonly` will help:

```
class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('content','project','status')

    title= forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'id': 'title',
                                                          'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

And in your view u need to prepopulate title field with original value, like this:

```
   some_form = NewIssueForm()        
   some_form.fields['title'].initial = "some_title"
```